# PHP curl post always return 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to make a php curl to make a post in this link: http://g3cs.uesc.com/dsse1.asp, doing it in browser it works fine, ie: put some code like: 41225295 at input field and click at button it will make a post to http://g3cs.uesc.com/dsse2.asp, my code is:

```
<?php
function __curl($url,$p=NULL,$h=NULL,$ssl=0,$c=NULL,$tm=690,$header=0)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    $opts = array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_HEADER => $header,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => $ssl,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)',
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => $tm,
    CURLOPT_REFERER => 'http://g3cs.uesc.com/dsse1.asp'
    );

    if($p)
    {
        $opts[CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST] = 'POST';
        $opts[CURLOPT_POST] = 1;
        $opts[CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS] = http_build_query($p);
    }
    if($h) $opts[CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER] = $h;
    if($c) $opts[CURLOPT_COOKIE] = $c;

    curl_setopt_array($ch,$opts);
    $out = curl_exec($ch);

    if(!$out)
    {
        echo curl_error($ch);
        exit(0);
    }

    curl_close($ch);

    return $out;
}

echo __curl('http://g3cs.uesc.com/dsse2.asp',array('opt'=>'0','inacn'=>'127','inref'=>'41225295'));
?>
```

it always return 500 Internal Server Error.

someone could help me with some hints?

Thanks.

Comment: Look at your error logs.

Comment: I think you forgot `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` header

Comment: @SLY, i add CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'), but still same error

Comment: Ah, I see, you should delete `http_build_query`

Comment: @SLY, hum why? it could make some difference?

Comment: I was wrong, all you need is to send `Content-Type: multipart/form-data` header and in case of array php-curl do it automatically. Looks like this is the requirement of this particular form.

Comment: Check webserver logfiles

Comment: @CharlotteDunois, u mean about the g3cs website server?

Comment: No, yours. That's where the HTTP 500 happens.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois, but it http 500 come from remote server, well u mean error log file of apache?

Answer (score 0):

Can you make sure the server-side script (dsse2.asp) has no issues. I strongly believe Status 500 is something related to server-side script. it has nothing to do with your client

Comment: Well idk cuz the server side script is not mine

Comment: i'm trying to figured out ... i tried alot of things, maybe is not possible to make a php curl of this link?